# Array destruction in loops

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

let's say I have a standart array declaration inside a loop, where the array is at known size:

```
for (int i = 0; i < some_condition; ++i){
    int arr[LENGTH];
    arr = someting \\more operations with arr here
}
```

What happens behind the scenes with the memory? does the program "clean" the memory allocated for the array every loop, using only LENGTH memory space overall, or do all the declarations accumulate over the loops, ending up using LENGTH * some_condition memory space?

Please note that this is intentionally no dynamic allocation.

Comment: Yes it does. ..

Comment: `arr = someting` is wrong syntax. BTW, in each iteration `LENGTH` size array will be created and will have block scope. It's lifetime will be ended once the `for` loop block ends.

Comment: **"does the program "clean" the memory?"** That depends on your definition of "clean", and what the compiler does at that point will be completely implementation defined. The memory for `arr` is released for reuse by your code when the function returns. (there is no requirement it be set to all zero, etc.. -- that is one of the reasons you initialize your variables, You new variable declared after the loop ends may have been part of `arr`)

Comment: 'arr' is rvalue :(